# Yolo training yolo with own dataset

Tags: opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, yolo

I want to build a database with Yolo and this is my first time working with deep learning

1. how can I build a database for Yolo and train it?
2. How do I get the weights of the classifications?
3. Is it too difficult for someone new to Deep Learning?

Comment: Try working with [gluonCV](https://gluon-cv.mxnet.io/index.html). Will probably take you a few good days before your model starts running.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it with ease!! and welcome to the Deep learning Community. You are welcome.

First download the darknet folder from [Link](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet)

Go inside the folder and type make in command prompt

```
git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet
cd darknet
make
```

Define these files -

```
data/custom.names
data/images
data/train.txt
data/test.txt
```

Now its time to label the images using [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) and save it in YOLO format which will generate corresponding label .txt files for the images dataset.

[image: LabelImg labelling guide]

Labels of our objects should be saved in data/custom.names.

[image: Custom.names example]

Using the script you can split the dataset into train and test-

```
import glob, os

dataset_path = '/media/subham/Data1/deep_learning/usecase/yolov3/images'

# Percentage of images to be used for the test set
percentage_test = 20

# Create and/or truncate train.txt and test.txt
file_train = open('train.txt', 'w')  
file_test = open('test.txt', 'w')

# Populate train.txt and test.txt
counter = 1  
index_test = round(100 / percentage_test)  
for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dataset_path, "*.jpg")):  
    title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))

    if counter == index_test+1:
        counter = 1
        file_test.write(dataset_path + "/" + title + '.jpg' + "\n")
    else:
        file_train.write(dataset_path + "/" + title + '.jpg' + "\n")
        counter = counter + 1
```

For train our object detector we can use the existing pre trained weights that are already trained on huge data sets. From [here](https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74) we can download the pre trained weights to the root directory.

Create a yolo-custom.data file in the custom_data directory which should contain information regarding the train and test data sets

```
classes=2
train=custom_data/train.txt
valid=custom_data/test.txt
names=custom_data/custom.names
backup=backup/
```

Now we have to make changes in our yolov3.cfg for training our model. For two classes. Based on the required performance we can select the YOLOv3 configuration file. For this example we will be using yolov3.cfg. We can duplicate the file from cfg/yolov3.cfg to custom_data/cfg/yolov3-custom.cfg

The maximum number of iterations for which our network should be trained is set with the param max_batches=4000. Also update steps=3200,3600 which is 80%, 90% of max_batches.
We will need to update the classes and filters params of [yolo] and [convolutional] layers that are just before the [yolo] layers.
In this example since we have a single class (tesla) we will update the classes param in the [yolo] layers to 1 at line numbers: 610, 696, 783
Similarly we will need to update the filters param based on the classes count filters=(classes + 5) * 3. For two classes we should set filters=21 at line numbers: 603, 689, 776
All the configuration changes are made to custom_data/cfg/yolov3-custom.cfg

Now, we have defined all the necessary items for training the YOLOv3 model. To train-

```
./darknet detector train custom_data/detector.data custom_data/cfg/yolov3-custom.cfg darknet53.conv.74
```

Comment: Can yolo only identify pre-trained objects?  I mean can identify an object with the same Yolo structure like curve ?

Answer (score 1):

Also you can mark bounded boxes of objects in images for training Yolo [right in your web browser](https://github.com/yolo-mark-pwa/yolo-mark-pwa.github.io), just open url. This tool is deployed to GitHub Pages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this popular forked darknet repository https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet. The author describes many steps that will help you to build and use your own Yolo detector model.

1. How to build your own custom dataset and train it? Follow this [step](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) . He suggests to use Yolo Mark labeling tool to build your dataset, but you can also try another tool as described in [here](https://timebutt.github.io/static/how-to-train-yolov2-to-detect-custom-objects/) and [here](https://medium.com/@manivannan_data/how-to-train-yolov3-to-detect-custom-objects-ccbcafeb13d2).
2. How to get the weights? The weights will be stored in `darknet/backup/` directory after every 1000 iterations (you can adjust this value later). The link above explains everything about how to make and use the weights file.
3. I don't think it will be so difficult if you already know math, statistic and programming. Learning the basic neural network like perceptron, MLP then move to modern Machine Learning is a good start. Then you might want to expand your knowledge to Computer Vision related or NLP related area

Comment: Thanks, in Yolo, like mlp, do we have to specify neural network layers manually?  Or are the layers automatically set?

Comment: @diegokabir you don't have to. Yolo comes in many different type of architecture, there are yolo, yolov2, yolov3, yolov3 tiny, yolov3 spp, etc. All of the pre-trained model and definition have been provided by the author so you don't have to modify the layers unless you really want to make some modifications

Comment: i have images that don't exist in any datasets, so I have to create the datasets first, then train it, so do I have to specify the layers myself?

Comment: @diegokabir no, but you have to change the `filters`, `classes` parameter in the cfg file, as described in https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects . You might want to calculate your own anchor boxes value for your own dataset, just follow the guide on the link

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of OS you have. You can either hit up https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet [especially for Windows] or stick to https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.
Steps to do so:

- 1) Setup darknet as detailed in the posts.
- 2) I used LabelIMG to label my images. make sure that the format
  you save the images is in YOLO. If you save using the PascalVOC format or others you can write scripts to change it to the format that darknet expects.[YOLO]. Also, make sure that you do not change your labels file. If you want to add new labels, at it at the end of the file, not in between. YOLO format is quite different, so your previously labelled images may get messed up if you make changes in between the classes.
- 3)The weights will be generated as you train your model in a specific folder in darknet.[If you need more details I am happy to help answer that]. You can download the .74 file in YOLO and start training. The input to train needs a built darknet.exe a cfg file a .74 file and your training data location/access.

The setup is draconian, the process itself is not.

Answer (score 0):

To build your own dataset, you should use LabelImg. It's a free and very easy software which will produce for you all the files you need to build a dataset. In fact, because you are working with yolo, you need a txt file for each of your image which will contain important information like bbox coordinates, label name. All these txt files are automatically produced by LabelImg so all you have to do is open the directory which contains all your images with LabelImg, and start the labelisation. Then, well you will have all your txt files, you will also need to create some other files in order to start training (see https://blog.francium.tech/custom-object-training-and-detection-with-yolov3-darknet-and-opencv-41542f2ff44e).

Comment: Finally a yolo how-to that works!

Answer (score 0):

To create your own dataset in Yolo format, you can use [RoboFlow](https://roboflow.com/). It helps you to organize, label, annotate your image dataset and even train your model. at the end you can test your model with an image, video or webcam.